# How to do face recognition on images and determining if the faces in it is known?

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

Currently, I'm making a face recognition program where I have a KNOWN_FACES folder that is accessed by program to recognise known faces in an unidentified image. I test the program on a image that should return *'Unknown'* on all faces, but I'm having trouble with getting rectangles on all the faces, and then saving the image in an *image_output* folder.

FOLDER STRUCTURE.

Known images:
*my_project//KNOWN_FACES//"ALL FACES HERE"*

Output folder:
*my_project//image_output//*

And I have a *faces.jpg* in the directory, where my program is located. In my code, I'm pretty sure that there's something wrong with how I try to **draw** rectangles around each face and display their name right under the rectangle. (Almost at the bottom of the program.)

### My Code

I only have this one program, which is a modification of [THIS](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/find_faces_in_picture.py) piece of code from the maker of the face_recognition module.

Here is *image_face_recognition.py*:

```
from PIL import Image
import face_recognition
import cv2

# Load Unidentified faces
image = face_recognition.load_image_file("faces.jpg")

# face1
face1_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("KNOWN_FACES//face1.jpg")
face1_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(face1_image)[0]

# face2
face2_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("KNOWN_FACES//face2.jpg")
face2_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(face2_image)[0]

# face3
face3_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("KNOWN_FACES//face3.jpg")
face3_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(face3_image)[0]

# face4
face4_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("KNOWN_FACES//face4.jpg")
face4_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(face4_image)[0]

# Create arrays of known face encodings and their names
known_face_encodings = [
    face1_face_encoding,
    face2_face_encoding,
    face3_face_encoding,
    face4_face_encoding
]
known_face_names = [
    "FACE1",
    "FACE2",
    "FACE3",
    "FACE4"
]

# Find all the faces in the image using the default HOG-based model.
# This method is fairly accurate, but not as accurate as the CNN model and not GPU accelerated.
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)

print("I found {} face(s) in this photograph.".format(len(face_locations)))

# Then compare faces with known faces, and save an image that contains
# rectangles around EACH face.

# Find all the face encodings in the image.
face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(image, face_locations)

face_names = []
for face_encoding in face_encodings:
    # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
    matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
    name = "Unknown"

    # If a match was found in known_face_encodings, just use the first one.
    if True in matches:
        first_match_index = matches.index(True)
        name = known_face_names[first_match_index]

    face_names.append(name)

    # Return final image.
    for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
        # Scale back up face locations since the image was scaled to 1/5 size.
        top *= 5
        right *= 5
        bottom *= 5
        left *= 5

        # Draw a box around the face.
        cv2.rectangle(image, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # Draw a label with a name below the face.
        # See, this is where I think I messed up.
        # DOESN'T WORK (I think).
        cv2.rectangle(image, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.putText(image, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)


# Finally, save the image to image_output folder.
final_image = Image.fromarray(image)
final_image.save("image_output/FACE_REC_PICTURE.png")
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Martin The problem is that I’m trying to *draw* a rectangle around each face in an unidentified image of faces. If faces were found draw the rectangle with *text* right under the rectangle that is either showing ‘Unknown’ if it’s NOT a known face or ‘The Name’ IF it’s a known face, and after doing that export the original image WITH the rectangles applies to the image.

Comment: I know exactly what you want to do, but I have no idea what is the problem? Is the rectangle drawn elsewhere? Is there nothing recognized? Is the rectangle ok but text is outside? Is there some Error?

Comment: @Martin Sorry for the misunderstanding. I don’t know EXACTLY what is happening, but I cannot see *any* rectangles at all...

Comment: Fine, then we will go step by step. Firstly, remove rescaling (TOP *= 5). I dont actually see any image rescale at all, so maybe you are drawing rectangle outside of the the image

Comment: @Martin Ok. I will do.

Comment: And please, load image with opencv. Face_recognition is great library, but you dont want it to open images or recognize face locations. Recognizing face location is god damn slow. You may want to use Haar recognition for frontal faces and side faces. (I did project on this so I think you will got there at some point)

Comment: I think I got your problem. You think you have rescaled image. Fine maybe it is, but if you want to rescale it back, besides coordinates you also need to rescale image. So before Drawing rectangle, resize image -> cv2.resize(img,(0,0),fx=5,fy=5)

Comment: @Martin Wow, I'm SOO dumb. I see it all now. And also thanks for your great advice about using Haar recognition. I will *definitely* try that out! Thanks!!

Comment: Its fine. Playing with coordinates always leads to mistakes like this. This will not be your last time :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to resize image before drawing rectangle

```
#resize image TOO
image = cv2.resize(image,(0,0),fx=5,fy=5)
for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
        # Scale back up face locations since the image was scaled to 1/5 size.
        top *= 5
        right *= 5
        bottom *= 5
        left *= 5



        # Draw a box around the face.
        cv2.rectangle(image, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)


        cv2.rectangle(image, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.putText(image, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)
```

Besides that, you have twice this line

```
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)
```

in your script. In general I wouldnt mention that, but this one is pretty slow function, so you dont want to do it twice.

**In my humble opinion,** and from my experience, you do this ***rescaling*** because finding face locations with Face_recognition library is god damn slow. If I may intervene,

Look at **Haar cascades** - for finding frontal and side face locations.

It does the same job, but you need to integrate it in your program, which is not problem at all. Its basicly the same like

```
face_recognition.face_locations(image)
```

While face_recognition library can find face locations up to 60s.. Haar cascades, even though little bit less accurate and reliable, can do it up to 1s. You will not need to rescale you image and play with coordinates

Comment: Thanks ALOT! I see. I will definitely try out the Haar recognition.